# Downloading a file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script in PowerShell to download a file from a web page.

Command being used is:

```
wget 'http://AnyWeb.com/test/test.txt' -outfile 'F:\junk\TEST2.txt'
```

The command runs, but it only downloads part of the file and then stops downloading.

I also tried the following and the same result:

```
$url = 'http://AnyWeb.com/test/test.txt'
$output = 'F:\junk\test2.txt'
$start_time = Get-Date
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-OutPut "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($Start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Any ideas as to why it would stop downloading?

Comment: That should be OK, I would suggest to run Wireshark and start it capturing with the filter: `http.request.full_uri == "http://AnyWeb.com/test/test.txt"`.  I guess you need to update that. Once it fails.  Stop the capture, right click on the filtered result and choose "Follow -> TCP Stream".  Do you see the server maybe resetting the connection?  Does it always stop at the same point? Have you tried a few sample downloads, E.g. `http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip`. Same result?

Comment: If I open Powershell and type or paste the line (ie: not run in a script), it works fine and downloads the whole file. When run with the script the file always stops at the same point. The complete file size is over 49Mb, and only about 180K downloads.

Comment: Does using this file suffer the same issue: `http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip`

Comment: The wget worked in both as a manual entry in Powershell and in a PS1 file.

Comment: I will play some more. I may have messed up the PS1 file. I will try again and post my results.

Comment: Tried this command and I'm only getting 175k file and it should be just about 50Mb

Comment: wget "http://iptv-epg.com/6972-z9aqly.m3u" -outfile "P:\SMSABC\EPG\IPEPG-ETER20180623.XML"

Comment: I don't really follow all your recent comments.  In the case where it fails using the script, does a different URL, e.g. `http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip` also fail?  Can we rule out the file type/source?  I think the next step has to be Wireshark as detailed above.  Ideally create a packet trace from the "work" case where you download the same file opening Powershell and paste the line (i.e. not run the script).  Maybe link the working and failing pcap.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using the one of the three suggestions from this article.

> 3 ways to download files with PowerShell
>
> https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell

Have you tried the others?
Did you encounter the same issue with the two other methods?

Not that what you are using should be problematic (I've personally never had issue with that method - though I no longer use that in preference for the .NET way for the performance gain), but a sanity check by using the other methods may point the way.